# very vs. much in sentences

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

> A *very* annoyed tone. (grammatically correct)
>
> He seemed *much* annoyed. (grammatically correct)

I would like to know if I wrote (or said) "He seemed *very* annoyed" whether the native speaker would consider it as being a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

> He seemed very annoyed.

The sentence seems natural. The adverb **very** modifies the adjective **annoyed**.